# If p → q then q → p?

Tags: boolean-logic, boolean-operations, boolean-algebra

I'm trying to get back into boolean algebra after many years without it, I'm currently working on an exercise that asks to verify if p → q or q → p are tautologies, p and q being very long expressions hard to simplify, yet p → q is very easy to prove a tautology using a truth table while q → p takes a lot longer to verify using a truth table.

Is the statement p → q ≡ q → p correct? I can't find concise info on this proposition but building the truth table makes it seem like it is correct.

If it is I could answer that since p → q is a tautology q → p is too.

Comment: Consider p = "person x is the current President of the US", q = "person x has white hair".  You are [affirming the consequent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affirming_the_consequent).

Comment: @NateEldredge [Perhaps not the best example to use](https://external-preview.redd.it/zcc1pBNOhwr58bU7eqiYwsawHxC8HjKCD0vJnSRzL0o.jpg?auto=webp&s=264ef0598012230e145e0fb525b0642508f5bb4e) - at least until Obama.

Comment: I mean the current President right now.  The current President does have white hair, but not every white-haired person is the President.  But I like Wikipedia's example better: p = "x is a dog", q = "x has four legs".

Answer (score 0):

When I understand your question right, then a look at the truth-table shows the following: 
a -> b = c  |  b -> a = c 
0 -> 0 = 1  |  0 -> 0 = 1 
0 -> 1 = 1  |  0 -> 1 = **0** 
1 -> 0 = **0**  |  1 -> 0 = 1 
1 -> 1 = 1  |  1 -> 1 = 1 
This show that a->b is not euqal to b->a. 
I hope this help a little bit.